# 404 error wnen url redirected to another controller of same app on linux server

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I have deployed my codeigniter application on linux server,when I am working locally it works fine but when I am hitting the controller or redirecting to another controller of same app giving out 404 error page not found.

All the needs I have googled of changing httpd.cong file, mod_rewrite_enable but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you please share your .htaccess file data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Also check that your controller name must start with upper letter ex:: `Mycontroller.php`

Comment: Please share more information. Please share your .htaccess

Comment: Check if it is working with `/index.php/uri/segmets/here` or `/index.php?/uri/segmets/here` in URL.